# Styling image inside iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, image

I have an image inside an iframe by setting the src attribute of the iframe:

```
<iframe src="path/to/my/image.jpg" class="myclass"></iframe>
```

The iframe has a fixed height and width. I want that image's width to fill the iframe, but its height would stay proportional to the width so the user would be able to scroll down the iframe to see the rest of the image.
How do I do this?
EDIT: JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/2LExA/

Comment: I deleted my answer, not realising it's an image. Either way, if you are using an image that belongs to you, why use an iframe?

Comment: because I didn't want the full image displayed. I wanted it to be displayed in an embedded frame through which the user can scroll.

Answer (score 3):

I set the src of the iframe to a page called show_image.php and passed the image url as query string:

```
<iframe src="show_image.php?src=path/to/image.jpg" class="foobar"></iframe>
```

Then in the show_image.php, I dropped an img with its src set to the query string and width to 100%:

```
<img src="<?php echo $_GET['src']; ?>" style="width:100%" />
```

Done!
Thanks to lukeocom's hint for mentioning that I should put the image in a separate page.

Answer (score 1):

you use an iframe primarily to display a separate html page, which would contain an image. You would therefore use css for that page  to style the image. You can use css to style the width of your iframe, but not its content.

Your other alternative is to place the image in a div, and style the image relative to that div.

html

```
<div><img src="yourimg" /></div>
```

css

```
div{width:600px;height:300px;}
img{width:50%;}
```

Comment: The iframe is dynamically loaded into the page and I'm using a different src value for each iframe.

Comment: I solved it by setting the src to a php page called show_image.php, then passed the image url as query string. In the page I dropped an img and set its src to the passed query string, and set it's width style to 100%. This did the trick, thanks to your hint for using another page for the image. +1, but i'm going to post my own answer since this is not complete.