# How to set width of image inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set the width of image inside of iframe.

By default when an image is set inside iframe and if the image is in high resolution then the iframe will be scrollable

Comment: use javascript and/or css to achieve your goal

Comment: I tried but its not working

Comment: share with us what you tried, and we will endeavour to help you fix it

Comment: you can't access element of iframe if you are loading another domain in iframe

Comment: <iframe src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg" id="myframe">
 
</iframe>


The content inside should be fixed with that iframe it should not be scrollable

Comment: Ref. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I am just giving the example link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Comment: @Sarfarazbheda is prescient - you can't twiddle with the innards of an iframe in a different domain

Comment: so, this example is "what you've tried" ... there's no javascript or css ... you've tried to load an iframe, and it didn't load how you wanted? am I correct in assuming you've tried **no** css and **no** javascript to fix the issue you are having with your code?

Comment: Below is the code i tried





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css" id="cssID">
img
{
    width: 10% !important;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<iframe src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg" id="myframe">
 
</iframe>


</body>
</html>

<script>
 $(function () {
        $("#myframe").contents().find("head")[0].appendChild(cssID);
    });
</script>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling image inside iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082459/styling-image-inside-iframe)

Comment: See the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/chandraphp/xnomohmb/

i want that image inside of iframe should be fit to that frame it should not be scrollable

Answer (score 1):

If both frames are on the same domain and there is no restriction with Same Domain Policy, you can use the following code from the "parent" frame to change an image in the "child" iframe.

Pseudo code, you need to actually edit it to match your DOM:

```
document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.getElementById('yourImageId').width = '100';
```

Notes: In case iframe is on a different domain, you have limited access for security reasons.

More details here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: I agreed with Gibbok

Comment: <iframe src="logo.jpg" id="myframe"> </iframe>

From the above we cant get the image id and we cant set any id to image, here we are not using any image tag, we are loading from iframe

Comment: See the fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/chandraphp/xnomohmb/

i want that image inside of iframe should be fit to that frame it should not be scrollable

Comment: @ChandraKumar content in your iframe should be a valid HTML document, you are basically adding as SRC of an iframe an url to an image. With you code you cannot set any property of your image not with CSS not with JS, only things you can do is changing style for your iframe tag on the parent frame.

Comment: How and where can we set the styling for iframe.

If we provide width to iframe then ifrane width will be effected.

Comment: @ChandraKumar look here: https://jsfiddle.net/xnomohmb/1/ here all properties you can change for an iframe http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: @ChandraKumar if you think my answer and comments helped you out with your question, please do not forget to accept  this answer using the "TICK" icon on its left side :). Thanks for your cooperation.