# How to position an image inside the iframe with html?

Tags: html, css, iframe, position

I'm trying to position an image inside the iframe, I researched but couldn't find what i needed.

Here's what I did,

The html

```
<div class="modal-body description">
                <div class="modal-body description">
                    <table class="ui very basic celled table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <iframe frameborder="0" width="300" height="200" id="sigImage"  onloadeddata="window.frames.scrollTo(300,500)"  src="~/Content/images/signature.png" name="sigImage"></iframe>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>                    
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Here I tried to use the method (first I use `onload`) `onloadeddata` to position the image according to my need. Basically I have an image and i want to position a part of an image inside iframe on load.
 The user can then scroll through the image to see other areas of the image.
 How do I implement this?
 Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way but you have to use PHP, where  you will store the path of your image file. This was discussed before.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082459/styling-image-inside-iframe) is the link so that you can refer.

Comment: No I just need to point a specific part of the image when loading. The while image is loaded to the iframe but a specific image part I want to show from the iframe.